# Running-time complexity of two nested loops: quadratic or linear?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

```
int Solution::diffPossible(vector<int> &A, int B) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = i+1; j < A.size(); j++)
          if ((A[j]-A[i]) == B)
             return 1;      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the solution to a simple question where we are supposed to write a code with time complexity less than or equal to O(n). I think the time complexity of this code is O(n^2) but still it got accepted. So, I am in doubt please tell me the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze the worst-case scenario, i.e. when the condition of the `if`-statement in the inner loop, `(A[j]-A[i]) == B`, is never fulfilled, and therefore the statement `return 1` is never executed.

If we denote `A.size()` as `n`, the comparison in the inner loop is performed `n-1` times for the first iteration of the outer loop, then `n-2` times for the second iteration, and so on...

So, the number of the comparisons performed in the inner loop for this *worst-case* scenario is (by calculating the sum of the resulting [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) below):

```
n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 = (n-1)n/2 = (n^2 - n)/2
^                 ^
|_________________|
     n-1 terms
```

Therefore, the running-time complexity is quadratic, i.e., O(n^2), and not O(n).